# Wordpress - Show Tags only with more than 1 post

Tags: wordpress, tags

In my template, on the entry.php, I am trying to list the tags associated with a specific post. However, I only want to show tags that have MORE THAN ONE post associated with it.

Here is my query...

```
$args  = array(
        'meta_key' => 'ratings_average', // WP-Rating Plugin Rating Value
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'cat' => $cat_id,
        'posts_per_page' => 10,
        'paged' => $paged,
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And in the loop, I can list the tags just fine:

```
<?php if(has_tag()) { 
   ?><label>TAGS: </label><?php // the_tags( '', ', ', '' ); 
   $tags_array = get_tags( $args );
} ?>
```

...but its shows tags that have only one post.

I'd also like to be able to list the number of posts associated with each tag. The results would look something like this...

> Fruits (3), Vegetables (4), Meats (2)

And the tag would be a link to the TAG page, but the number would not be a link.

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: And what are you passing as `$args` to the `get_tags()` function?

Comment: I added the args and query above...